# How can I make an Angular Material accordion fit a container?

Tags: angular-material, accordion, angular-flex-layout

I'd like to have an accordion that fits a particular grid row in my flex layout. Basically, the container element for the accordion would be the same height as the other column in the row. Currently, AM expansion panels disregard parent height and either don't fill the parent or push its height to fit the accordion's content.

[AM expansion panel as accordion example](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples)

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qkjylapbkqok?file=app%2Fexpansion-steps-example.ts)

Here's a simplified scenario:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex> <!-- THIS COLUMN WOULD DETERMINE ROW HEIGHT -->
        ...
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="30%"> <!-- THIS COLUMN WOULD CONSTRAIN THE ACCORDION -->
        <mat-accordion displayMode="flat">
            <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>Title One</mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                <p>Blah.</p>

                <p>Blah.</p>

                <p>Blah.</p>
            </mat-expansion-panel>

            <mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>Title Two</mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

My criteria are fairly simple:

- The accordion fills the entire column even if content doesn't require the space (the open panel would stretch as needed)
- Accordion panels have internal scrolling if they're taller than what the parent element can accommodate
- Animations remain delightful

Thanks much.